# Will everything imported by a wildcard use directive ("use some_crate::*") be included in the binary?

Tags: rust

If I import everything using `*` in Rust's `use`, does the built file include only what I use in the import?
e.g. `use std::io::prelude::*`

Comment: A use directive only changes what names are in scope, so the compiler can resolve these names as intended. It doesn't have any effect on linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through LLVM, Rust benefits from aggressive dead code elimination.

In fact, you can see that work by default: unless `no_std`, code implicitly has [the standard prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/index.html) in-scope.

For instance, compare trivial printing code versus trivial printing code with a (useless) `Box` invocation: https://godbolt.org/z/3KWbGeqsh

Only the latter has the relevant `Box` code generated and compiled in.

Comment: @RichardNeumann fair enough